# Unspecified error during import of AudioClip

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to import a fairly large mp3 file into Unity (about 200 MB) and I keep getting the error:

```
Unspecified error during import of AudioClip Assets/Audio/audio.mp3
```

The only solution I was able to find was "touching" the file to reset the timestamps but that did not work.
I am on Windows 10.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The asset has to be processed when it's imported which can suck up significant memory. A 200MB MP3 can consume a LOT more than that when decompressed. How much RAM do you have, and have you monitored usage during the import process?

Comment: I have 32gb of RAM, I tried with all my chrome tabs closed and all other applications closed as well. Same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to "touch" the file to reset the modified date or you can check if the other sound with audio clip as well

Comment: Bro I told you in my question I already tried to touch it and it didn't work